# Wordpress - get category name as select option value

Tags: php, wordpress

I've got a select dropdown which outputs all the available categories of the Wordpress site. Now I've been trying to also set the `value` of each option to the category name. This is my code:

```
<select id="test">
   <option value="one">Select Case Study Category</option>
     <?php $categories =  get_categories('');  
      foreach  ($categories as $category) {
       echo '<option value='.$category->name.'>'.$category-
       >name.'</option> ';
      }
    ?>
```

This works for a couple of categories such as "Uncategorised" but it doesn't work for categories with a space in them so for example "Case Study". For those categories it sets the value as `<option value= "Case" study>`
So it obviously seems to be an issue with the spaces, but anybody got any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Use this :- htmlspecialchars($category->name); Not sure if it works or not..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use

```
echo '<option value="'.$category->name.'">'.$category-
   >name.'</option> ';
```

not

```
echo '<option value='.$category->name.'>'.$category-
   >name.'</option> ';
```

you missed `"` in value attribute